# Cannot edit html in Chrome/FF devtools--Ubuntu 20

Tags: google-chrome

It seems that Ubuntu 20 is preventing browsers from accessing local folders thus one can view the html ( say in Chrome devtools) but cannot edit. In the past one could have added the folder and allow the browser to do just that.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1247387/edit) to include an example so we can reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In previous Chrome versions there was a plus icon you could click and add a working folder to your devtools' list of working directories. Currently all you have to do is drag your folder from your hard drive into the browser area of devtools' and approve there security prompt. Good luck!